# All average's combinations under apache pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I just start to develop with apache pig.
I have a file stored on the HDFS Measurements.csv structured as follow

```
    1;0x3333333333331091;21.2;67.5;2.1;2.0;12.2;15/04/2014 15:50    
    2;0x3333333333331091;21.2;67.4;2.1;12.0;8.5;15/04/2014 14:22
    3;0x3333333333331091;21.2;67.4;2.1;18.0;7.2;15/04/2014 14:22
    4;0x3333333333331091;21.2;69.5;2.1;19.0;3.2;15/04/2014 14:22
    5;0x3333333333331091;21.2;67.5;2.1;21.0;13.5;15/04/2014 14:22
    6;0x3333333333331091;21.3;69.4;2.1;14.0;15.1;15/04/2014 14:22
    7;0x3333333333331091;21.3;70.4;2.1;19.0;16.7;15/04/2014 14:22
    8;0x3333333333331091;21.2;68.3;2.1;8.0;22.1;15/04/2014 14:22
    9;0x3333333333331091;21.3;67.3;2.1;2.0;11.8;15/04/2014 14:23
    10;0x3333333333331091;21.3;67.4;2.0;32.0;19.1;15/04/2014 14:23
```

I load it with the command:

```
Mesure = LOAD 'dataTest/measurements.csv' USING PigStorage(';') as (idSensor:int, address:chararray, temperature:float, humidity:float, voltage:float, locX:float, locY:float, time:chararray );
```

What I need to do is

- To calculate the averages of temperature of all pairs including the temperature of the first line.
- To calculate the averages of temperature composed by 3 temperatures including the temperature of the first line
- To calculate the average of temperature composed of composed of 9 temperatures of average including the temperature of the first line
- And finally calculate the obe average composed by all the temperatures in the file.

Can someone show me the way to do this with apache pig.

---

After testing hardly to answer myselft i finally obtained the following results.

I was able to generate permutation of temperature. but what i want is to eliminate redundancy by listing the combinations instead of permtations.

I proceed as follow, first, i select only the a list of temperature, then i did it twice so i can applay the cross operator over the two list.

```
TEMP1 = FOREACH Mesure GENERATE temperature as temp1;
TEMP2 = FOREACH Mesure GENERATE temperature as temp2;
```

After that i cross :

```
Result = CROSS TEMP1,TEMP2;
```

And it display something like this :

```
(21.3,21.3)
(21.3,21.3)
(21.3,21.2)
(21.3,21.3)
(21.3,21.3)
(21.3,21.2)
(21.3,21.2)
(21.3,21.2)
(21.3,21.2)
(21.3,21.2)
(21.3,21.3)
....
```

this is what i was able to do, now i'm asking, is there something that can delete the replication of pairs ? and when it is done how to calculate the average of each pair.

Comment: Regarding the 1st point, what do you mean by average of temperature of all pairs ? You want to group 2 consecutive records together and then find avg ? Like average of 1st & 2nd is 21.2 and 3rd  &4th, and so on ? Or to find average of all records? Kindly specify.

Comment: what i need to do is something like that : average(21.2,21.2) the first and second line,  average(21.2,21.2) the first and third line ... until calculating average(21.2,21.3) the first and last line. when i finish calculating the average of pairs i launch calculating the average composed by three values, and always including the temperature of the first line. and i keep going until calculating the average composed of all values of temperature.

Comment: I'm really interested in this question.  What do you expect the output to look like?  For instance, a file for the 2s, a file for the 3s,...,etc... or one file.  And how do you want the averages situated?  columns or rows?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do to get the average for 2 lines -

```
Mesure = LOAD 'filename' using PigStorage(';') as (idSensor:int, address, temperature:float, h, v, locx, locy,t); --since I am concerned with only the temperature and idSensor so I don't care about other fields.

TEMP1 = FOREACH Mesure GENERATE idSensor as num, temperature as t;
TEMP2 = FOREACH Mesure GENERATE idSensor as num, temperature as t;
B2 = CROSS TEMP1, TEMP2;
C2 = FOREACH B2 GENERATE TEMP1.num as firstnum, TEMP2.num as secondnum, ((TEMP1.t = TEMP2.t)/2);
Res2 = FILTER C2 BY firstnum <= secondnum;
```

Here Res2 will give you results of averaging the two lines. Filter should be moved up for optimization. Same way you can perform for multi lines.

Hope this helps.